# 3DS Max - How to display bones as floating objects instead of lines beneath a mesh?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax

So I downloaded a rigged model for 3DS Max and it had something I'd never seen before. Bones as globes and rings floating outside the mesh for easy access and convenience instead of having to constantly access the object hierarchy or switch between layers to make sure everything is animating properly. How do I set up a model like this, or change a model rigged with regular lines between points as bones into a model like this?

[Rigged model with bone "helpers?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKnx.png)

Answer (score -1):

I see you are new here, but this website is for purely programming related questions. How to use any particular software is not the focus of this particular website.

I would suggest you take 3dsmax questions to cgtalk.com or perhaps as well to autodesk's own support website. Hm... looks like their old website for discussion forums, www.the-area.com doesn't work anymore. But I found this link: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max/ct-p/area-c1